# Merging a changeset to parent's parent in TFS

Tags: tfs, merge

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. In the TFS, we have the following:

```
-main
-sk\v1.0
-hotfix\v1.01
```

Here, `main` is the main branch. The branch `v1.0` is created from `main` in `sk` folder. The branch `v1.01` is created from `v1.0` in hotfix folder.

I did some changes in `v1.01`. Now I want to merge them back to `main` without affecting `v1.0`. From Source Control Explorer, I right clicked on `v1.01` and selected `Merge...` from Branching and Merging menu. In the resulting dialog box, there was a combobox which lists all target branches where merge can be performed. That combobox only lists `v1.0`.

How can I merge changes in `v1.01` to `main` without affecting `v1.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in future, if this is the workflow you wish to make, then you should branch `v1.01` from `main` rather than from `v1.0`.  That way, you could merge `v1.01` back into `main` without affecting `v1.0`.

However, as you haven't done that, I think your only choice would be to perform a `baseless merge`.

```
tf.exe merge /baseless <parent branch> <child branch>
```

That will create a parent - child relationship between between the two branches.  Check in your pending changes.

Now, back in VS, select the `v1.01` branch and click `File -> Source Control -> Branching and Merging -> Reparent`.  Select `Main` from the pop up window.  You should now be able to merge between these two branches.

See [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/jehan/archive/2011/03/19/branch-and-merge-improvements-in-tfs2010.aspx) for more info.